# Randomly select one/more functions from collection and apply combinations

Tags: python, function

I have a list of n functions: `f1(),f2()..fn()` etc and need to select n randomly and apply one/more of those in sequence to an object. What's the Pythonic way to do this?

The use-case is to generate augmentations for images (for training an ML model) from a set of images, and apply (one/more) augmentation functions to an image.

Comment: You can randomly select one of the functions using `random.choice()`.

Comment: @martineau I am of course aware of random.choice()...my question was how to apply combinations of functions in a pythonic way. Your response is much appreciated.

Comment: You may be able to use `itertools.combinations()` to generate them. You need to make your question more concrete, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question this could be done using reduce.

> Assumption:
>
> 1. You have a list of functions f1, ... fN
> 2. You want to select a sublist randomly, say k of them.
> 3. You want to apply the sublist in sequence to an object

**Solution using reduce**

```
from functools import reduce
#from numpy.random import choice   # use if your Python < 3.6
from random import choices         # available in Python 3.6+

# Define function on object (number in this case)
# included print so we can see each function being called
def f1(x):
    print("func1 x + 1: {} -> {}".format(x, x+1))
    return x + 1

def f2(x):
    print("func2 x * 2: {} -> {}".format(x, x*2))
    return x * 2

def f3(x):
    print("func3 x % 2:  {} -> {}".format(x, x%2))
    return x % 2

def f4(x):
    print("func4 x - 5:  {} -> {}".format(x, x-5))
    return x - 5

def f5(x):
    print("func5 x / 2:  {} -> {}".format(x, x/2))
    return x / 2

def f6(x):
    print("func6 x * 3:  {} -> {}".format(x, x/2))
    return x / 2

def f7(x):
    print("func7 x * 5:  {} -> {}".format(x, x/2))
    return x / 2

def f8(x):
    print("func8 x / 10:  {} -> {}".format(x, x/2))
    return x / 2
```

# Function which applies a function to an object
    def apply_func(x, f):
        return f(x)

```
# List of functions
funcs = [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8]

# Test (choose 3 functions at random)
random_funcs = choices(funcs, k = 3)

# Apply the functions to object (value 1)
obj = 1
answer = reduce(apply_func, random_funcs, obj)
print('Answer:', answer)
```

**Example Output**

```
func1 x + 1: 3 -> 4
func7 x * 5:  4 -> 2.0
func4 x - 5:  2.0 -> -3.0
Answer: -3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this `functools.reduce(lambda acc, f: f(acc), random.sample(funs, n), image)`?